# IntelliSense complains about missing Microsoft.AspNetCore packages despite being there

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, blazor

In my Blazor application, on the client side, IntelliSense complains about a lot of Microsoft.AspNetCore packages although the project compiles and runs fine.

I get a lot of things like

```
The type or namespace name 'Mvc' does not exist in the namespace 'Microsoft.AspNetCore' (are you missing an assembly reference?)    
The type or namespace name 'Razor' does not exist in the namespace 'Microsoft.AspNetCore' (are you missing an assembly reference?)  
...
```

Things like

```
@inject HttpClient Http
```

are also underlined with red squigglies.

The project builds and runs perfectly.

What is wrong here?

## Followup 1

Because I was asked for all versions:

- Visual Studio 2019, 16.0.2
- Microsoft.AspNetCore.Blazor.Templates::3.0.0-preview4-19216-03
- In my project:

```
Id                                  Versions                                 ProjectName                                                                                
--                                  --------                                 -----------                                                                                
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Blazor.Build   {3.0.0-preview4-19216-03}                MyBlazorApp.Client                                                                          
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Blazor         {3.0.0-preview4-19216-03}                MyBlazorApp.Client                                                                          
NETStandard.Library                 {2.0.3}                                  MyBlazorApp.Client
```

Comment: Cache. 1) Clean solution, 2) close VS, 3) delete bin/obj folders, 4) reopen VS

Comment: This does not help. The errors reappear.

Comment: Post all the package version, you VS version and if still applicable, the Blazor tools version.

Comment: Are you using VS2019 or VS2019 Preview?  (it's a very big difference)

Comment: @HenkHolterman I just added the versions referenced in my client package

Answer (score 4):

You need Visual Studio Preview version 16.1 or higher to work with 3.0.0-preview4 Blazor.

If that alone doesn't help, verify that you dont have any `.cshtml` files in your client project - they all have a `.razor` extension since 3.0.0-preview4. The presence of `.cshtml` file triggers a different SDK's behavior, requiring AspNetCore.Mvc namespace. Though Microsoft guys see it as a bug and probably will fix it.
https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore/issues/9640

Comment: I have no `cshtml` files, but I'll wait until 16.1 is out of preview, until now I take IntelliSense with a grain of salt, as I said, I have similar issues with a C++/CLI project and am used to this.

Comment: I can't tell if cshtml makes a difference, but I do see the same IntelliSense issues in the not-preview VS.

Comment: @rabejens - you can (and probably should for Blazor) install the Preview edition side-by-side.

Answer (score 0):

Shut down VS

Delete the .vs folder or the .suo file

Restart VS

Comment: I already did this multiple times but as soon as I build the project and reopen the files, the errors reappear.

Comment: @rabejens have you tried doing a rebuild. or deleting obj and bin folders and build again?

Comment: Yes, did everything in that line to no avail.

Comment: @rabejens usually this should clear intellisense cache. but you may try deleting the mentioned folders and restart windows as well. might be excessive but sometimes helps :)

Comment: I closed VS, did a `git clean -fdx` which deletes all these folders, and reopened VS and nothing helps. I'll just take IntelliSense with a grain of salt, I have similar problems accessing third-party native DLLs with C++/CLI and I got used to this as well.

Comment: maybe a reinstall or clean install of visual studio would help get round these kind of issues. might be you have broken dependencies

Answer (score 0):

uninstalling x86 version of .NET Core 3.0 Preview SDK
https://dotnet.microsoft.com/download/dotnet-core/3.0

Then installing the x64 again on Windows10 64bit fixed that issue for me